# Surfaces in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, matrix

I'm looking over some sample questions for OpenGL surfaces and came across this one and I'm not entirely sure how to do it. I know its matrix multiplication but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

[image]

on the bottom line that says : B(t) = Gb * Mb * T

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?  There are many examples in the web on the usage if Bernstein polynomials.Do you want to split bezier to segments?